# Asynchronous Inserts & UpdatesAsynchronous Inserts & Updates : NoSql and SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, mongodb, nosql

Reading this doc : http://metadata-standards.org/Document-library/Documents-by-number/WG2-N1501-N1550/WG2_N1537_SQL_Standard_and_NoSQL_Databases%202011-05.pdf it states for NoSql : 'Asynchronous Inserts & Updates" so this means that by default MongoDb issues these DB operations in a new thread whereas OracleDB and other SQL based DB's issue these operations sequentially ?

[image]

Does this mean that MongoDB has performance improvement over Oracle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ACID compliance does require serialization. Traditional RDBMS are typically ACID compliant by default with the option of using non-compliant modes.
With NOSQL platforms ACID is usually not an option. 
When they say there is no need for ACID what they mean is that these platforms are not suitable for applications that require ACID.